# How can I load a file from outside the application bundle?

Tags: macos, load, cocos2d-iphone

(I'm using cocos2d but that's not important i think)

Let's say the path is: /Users//1.tmx     //myname is replaced with my name

I'm trying to load a tmx file now:

```
tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"/Users/<myname>/1.tmx"];
```

but i get a error:

```
deallocing <CCTMXMapInfo: 0x100290480>
deallocing <CCTMXTilesetInfo: 0x10028fb50>
```

And I made a bt:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff82b322da in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x00007fff82b3294d in mach_msg ()
#2  0x00007fff89047932 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#3  0x00007fff89046dbf in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#4  0x00007fff812df91a in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#5  0x00007fff812df71f in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#6  0x00007fff812df5d8 in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode ()
#7  0x00007fff87e8fe64 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#8  0x00007fff87e8f7a9 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#9  0x00007fff87e5548b in -[NSApplication run] ()
#10 0x00007fff87e4e1a8 in NSApplicationMain ()
#11 0x0000000100002360 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff6f8) at /myproject/Classes/main.m:16
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you cannot access any file outside your app. Hence, trying to access file /Users//1.tmx will give you errors.

Comment: i'm programming for the mac not for ios

Comment: it says "iPhone" in one of your labels. Please change it then ;)

Comment: oh sorry :). could you help me?

Comment: I have never used cocos2D in the mac but by looking at some tutorial I would say that should work. Maybe you are not retaining tileMap?(So, tiledMap will be released before you really want to use it). As in this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d ,tiledMap var is retained because it is a property. in you case you don't seem to be doing that. try [tiledMap retain]; or make it a property ;) Hope it helps